# cellForRowAtIndexPath - objectAtIndex beyond bounds

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm having a little trouble with a tableView.
In this case, I have 4 sections.

Sections 0,1,2 have 1 cell.
Section 3 has 2 cells.

I'm now receiving the error,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'

Now I understand this is trying to reference a cell that isn't within the section?

Where I'm struggling is the count for each section is correct, like below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"Sections: %d", [_timetableDataArray count]);
    return [_timetableDataArray count];
}
```

This returns, as expected,

> Sections: 4

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
     NSDictionary *sectionContents = [_timetableDataArray objectAtIndex: section];
     NSLog(@"Section %d contains %d items", section, [sectionContents count]);

     return [sectionContents count];
}
```

The log for the above returns,

> Section 3 contains 2 items
>
> Section 0 contains 1 items
>
> Section 1 contains 1 items
>
> Section 2 contains 1 items

This is absolutely correct.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSLog(@"Iterating --- section: %d  row: %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);

}
```

The above method never even gets to NSLog. It crashes before this.

If I change my data array, so each section has 2 items, everything works fine.

Here is my data, http://pastebin.com/q5rbsvC8
I just don't understand where this crash is coming from when numberOfRowsInSection is returning the right number of rows per section.

I originally thought it might be a problem with 0-index's, but I changed these to start from 1 and it didn't help.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Did you try and return a UITableViewCell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? You can use the template code here

Comment: Hi, yeh I return a test cell before I load the data, this seems fine. It's once I've set the data for my tableView and try to reload it, the error happens. Thanks.

Comment: So it only crashes when you call `[_tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: @MrBr, you genius! I've just took out all the reloadData calls to double check, and it made clear it was a custom method I was calling directly after reloadData. So it wasn't the tableView at all. Stupid me! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `NSLog` for `section` in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` before

```
NSDictionary *sectionContents = [_timetableDataArray objectAtIndex: section];
```

to see if any unexpected values of `section` are coming in?

Comment: Hi, I get -- Section 3, Section 0, Section 1, Section 2.

Comment: I'm not sure why the ordering is strange, but I've read this doesn't matter.

Comment: I should add, if each section has 2 or more items, everything is fine.